# SQL multiple left join in subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-server-2012, left-join

Any idea on how to resolve this query dependency issue? Would subquery help? Database I'm using is sql server 2012.

```
FROM [Scheduling].[studentsection] AS [table027]  

Left JOIN [Grading].[StudentGradeBucket] AS [table028]
ON ([table028].[StudentSectionID] = [table027].[StudentSectionID])
    And (@0 = [table002].[label]) 

Left JOIN [Grading].[GradingPeriodGradeBucket] AS [table029]
ON [table028].[GradingPeriodGradeBucketID] = [table029].[GradingPeriodGradeBucketID] 

Left JOIN [Grading].[GradeBucket] AS [table002]  
ON [table029].[GradeBucketID] = [table002].[GradeBucketID] 

Left JOIN [Grading].[GradeBucketType] AS [table001]  
ON [table002].[GradeBucketTypeID] = [table001].[GradeBucketTypeID] 

Left JOIN [Grading].[GradeMark] AS [table022]  
ON [table028].[GradeMarkID] = [table022].[GradeMarkID]
```

The dependency issue I have is with this:

```
@0 = [table002].[label] //@0 is a string variable
```

Like the join hasn't been created yet but I need to use it to create the join for relationship [Grading].[StudentGradeBucket] or [table028]

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific with your question...what dependancy issue are you trying to solve?  (side note...that is the weirdest table aliasing I've seen in coding for some time)

Comment: I updated my post with more detail.  Let me know if you need more.

Comment: What is @0 - are you referring to a column in one of the tables, or is it a variable / parameter?  What database are you using?

Comment: @0 is a variable and db is sql server 2012.

Comment: And (@0 = [table002].[label])  it seems to me  you are using the table column before joining it

Comment: By joining to GradeBucket in that way you're creating a dependency between GradeBucket and StudentGradeBucket - which is what inner joins are for - see the first of my 3 solutions below for that version.

Answer (score 3):

That is weird circular join logic you are using and these table alias's you have chosen are making it more confusing.  Alias's should simplify, not confuse.  That said, I think it can just be moved to the where clause:

```
...
Left JOIN [Grading].[GradeMark] AS [table022]  ON [table028].[GradeMarkID] = [table022].[GradeMarkID] 
where  @0 = [table002].[label]
```

If that fails, you may need to redefine your logic...it seems a bit circular to me.

Comment: Isn't this going to return more records then necessary and performance would take a hit as well?

Comment: The reason for using this approach to table aliasing was due to the fact that the max length of a identifier is 128 characters.  We have some pretty deep relationship and when it is more than 128 character long it wouldn't work.  So this was the approach taken to resolve that issue.  Basically this is generated via a data layer (ORM) and when the sql is generated the actual table name are included as comment at the top.

Comment: This isn't the complete query, if you are interested I can send you the complete query.  I think we are going to try using Common Table Expressions (CTE) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I don't think there should be a performance hit...if you look at the explain plans, the way the SQL tuner is reading the query should be pretty much the same.  Joins used to be done entirely in the where clause...I might be wrong, but I think it should be the same execution plan.  That makes sense for the table aliasing, I should have guessed that it was auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @0 nvarchar(max) = 'label value'

select *

from [Scheduling].[studentsection] as ss  

left join [Grading].[StudentGradeBucket] as sgb  
    on sgb.[StudentSectionID] = ss.[StudentSectionID] 

inner join [Grading].[GradingPeriodGradeBucket] as gpgb  
    on gpgb.[GradingPeriodGradeBucketID] = sgb.[GradingPeriodGradeBucketID]

inner join [Grading].[GradeBucket] as gb  
    on gb.[GradeBucketID] = gpgb.[GradeBucketID] 
    and gb.[label] = @0 

left join [Grading].[GradeBucketType] as gbt  
    on gbt.[GradeBucketTypeID] = gb.[GradeBucketTypeID]

left join [Grading].[GradeMark] as gm  
    on gm.[GradeMarkID] = sgb.[GradeMarkID]
```

Or this if you really want left outer joins:

```
declare @0 nvarchar(max) = 'label value'

select *

from [Scheduling].[studentsection] as ss  

left join [Grading].[StudentGradeBucket] as sgb  
    on sgb.[StudentSectionID] = ss.[StudentSectionID] 

left join [Grading].[GradingPeriodGradeBucket] as gpgb  
    on gpgb.[GradingPeriodGradeBucketID] = sgb.[GradingPeriodGradeBucketID]

left join [Grading].[GradeBucket] as gb  
    on gb.[GradeBucketID] = gpgb.[GradeBucketID] 
    and gb.[label] = @0 

left join [Grading].[GradeBucketType] as gbt  
    on gbt.[GradeBucketTypeID] = gb.[GradeBucketTypeID]

left join [Grading].[GradeMark] as gm  
    on gm.[GradeMarkID] = sgb.[GradeMarkID]
```

Or if you need the logic of only returning results from the StudentGradeBucket when there's a matching GradeBucket record; this:

```
declare @0 nvarchar(max) = 'label value'

select *

from [Scheduling].[studentsection] as ss  

left join [Grading].[StudentGradeBucket] as sgb  
    on sgb.[StudentSectionID] = ss.[StudentSectionID] 

left join [Grading].[GradingPeriodGradeBucket] as gpgb  
    on gpgb.[GradingPeriodGradeBucketID] = sgb.[GradingPeriodGradeBucketID]

left join [Grading].[GradeBucket] as gb  
    on gb.[GradeBucketID] = gpgb.[GradeBucketID] 

left join [Grading].[GradeBucketType] as gbt  
    on gbt.[GradeBucketTypeID] = gb.[GradeBucketTypeID]

left join [Grading].[GradeMark] as gm  
    on gm.[GradeMarkID] = sgb.[GradeMarkID]

where 
( --filter on the gb label only if there's a result from the sgb table;
    sgb.[StudentSectionID] is null 
    or and gb.[label] = @0
)
```